# Shibbeloth Session Time-Out need to Redirect to error template

Tags: .net, api, authentication, iis-7, c#-3.0

I am using shibbeloth with IIS configuration and configured the session Time-Out with some value.

Our expectation is when the shibbeloth configured Time-Out is expired it's need to Redirect to error template.

But currently when session got time out the shibbeloth try to calling the IDP provider to re-login to create the fresh session.

Can some help us how to redirect to error template when session got timedout in shibbeloth.

Comment: This looks like Shibboleth logout doesn't clear cookies completely, it would not log out globally on the IDP, only on the local shibboleth.